# One servlet with multiple jsp's

Tags: jsp, servlets

Is it possible if I have a one function in my servlet then I will forward the getRequestDispacher to 4 jsp. Is it possible?

Comment: You can forgot to any jsp from four, but only one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

From Javadoc, RequestDispatcher defines an object that receives requests from the client and sends them to any resource (such as a servlet, HTML file, or JSP file) on the server.

Its clear that **at a time it can send to only one resource**.

[Refer this for documentation of RequestDispatcher.](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html)